# Converting this number to human readable form?

Tags: php, numbers

I have a database that is ported from an XLS file. My numbers are in this form

```
3.41002E+13
```

But the readable form should be : `34100224263318`

How can I convert the first form to the second?

Comment: not possible we can't predict 24263318 part

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? When you say "my numbers are in this form..." is this how they are shown in excel sheet? or is the E+NN form is how they are in the database? And how are you reading from the excel sheet to DB?

Comment: I think you'll have to add an excel tag and see if the export can be modified.

Comment: That number you show is `3.4100200000000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [number_format()](http://us.php.net/function.number_format)

> string **number_format**(float $number, int $decimals = 0, string $dec_point = '.', string $thousands_sep = ',' )

By default, thousands are seperated by `,`, that's why you need to pass all four arguments:

```
number_format(3.41002E+13, 0, ".", "");
34100200000000
```

As you can see, you have an additional problem: You lose precision - sort of at least: It was never there in the first place.

Comment: php> echo number_format(3.41002E+13, 0, ".", ""); -> `34100200000000`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `number_format`, check it out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1):

3.41002E+13 == 3.41002*10^13 == 3.41002 * 100000000000000

It is just a float type. If you want to achieve this you need to use number_format();

```
number_format(3.41002E+13) == 34100224263318
```

As phant0m commented if you use

```
number_format(1.11E-2) == 0,00111
```

but with integers you will be fine if you want a dot just use

```
number_format(1.11E-2, 5, '.', '') == 0.00111
```

Comment: You're missing the additional parameters.

Comment: @phant0m the output would be the same as the default setting is english notation 12212,11

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to get the exact number (e.g. 34100224263318) 
"Ex" stands for 10^x, which is used for numbers with a lot of digits as an approximation of the actual number. 
number_format is what you can use to get the approximation in a standard human-readable numerical version (Ex is readable too, but anyway).